# Numpy remove elements of 2D array based on percentile

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array whose columns are price values and the rows are dates. For every column I want to remove the extreme values (the X% lowest and X% highest values).

I can achieve this by computing the percentile and then applying a logical operator:

```
 idx_kd = np.logical_and(values>np.percentile(values,x) , values<np.percentile(values,100-x))
```

is there's a built-in functionality that automatically 'clips' data?

Answer (score 1):

There is, in fact, [`np.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html), but it seems to require its bounds as absolute numbers rather than percentiles, and it doesn't remove the outliers, but rather sets them to the min or max values respectively.